# Find all natural numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2 + y^2}}$ is a natural number

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Find all natural numbers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2 + y^2}} \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

My approaches:

- I saw that $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ are solutions. The fraction is a natural number if and only if $\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}$ divides $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2} \leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$.
- Then I tried by denoting $$
  \frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}}=k
  $$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and then
  $$
  \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=k\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2} \iff \sqrt{x}(x+3y)+\sqrt{y}(3x+y)=k^3(x^2+y^2)
  $$
  After that I squared each side of the previously found equation and looked at its natural and irrational parts, but I got stuck here.
- I have also tried by denoting $x=m^2$ and $y=n^2$: then the fraction becomes $\frac{m+n}{\sqrt[3]{m^4 + n^4}}$ and I saw that for $m=0$ and $n>0$, the only solution is $(0, 1)$ since $\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$ is a natural number for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ if $n=1$.

Comment: Why do you think that $x>y$?

Comment: @jjagmath I made a mistake. I wrote x^2-y^2 but it’s x^2+y^2 so that means it doesn’t have to be x>y. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: $(16,16)$ is another obvious solution. (I thought there are more in that direction, but no.)

Comment: Just a caution: In your last attempt, note that you assumed $x, y$ were perfect squares. While it turns out that this is true for the three solutions of this equation, it is not true in general for Diophantine equations involving radicals, You can sometimes have a common irrational multiplier to otherwise integer solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $x^2 + y^2 \ge \frac12(x + y)^2$ and $\sqrt x + \sqrt y \le \sqrt{2(x + y)}$.

Therefore $\frac{\sqrt x + \sqrt y}{\sqrt[3]{x^2 + y^2}} \le \frac{\sqrt{2(x + y)}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac12(x + y)^2}} = \sqrt[6]{\frac{32}{x + y}}$.

The left hand side is at least $1$, therefore we have $x + y \le 32$. Now just check every possibility to get all the solutions: $(x, y) = (0, 1)(1, 0)(16, 16)$.